# SVG transform="rotate(180)" does not work in Safari 11

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, safari

For some reason element

```
<svg width="1000" height="500" transform="rotate(180)">...</svg>
```

is shown as not rotated in Safari 11.

Chrome 63 renders it properly.

What's the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In SVG 1.1 `<svg>` elements [did not support transform attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement). In SVG 2 it is [proposed that they should](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#SVGElement).

Chrome and Firefox implement this part of the SVG 2 specification, Safari does not yet do so and IE11 never will.

You can achieve the same result in browsers that do not support this SVG 2 feature either by replacing the `<svg>` element by a `<g>` element or by creating an `<g>` child element on the `<svg>` element and putting the transform on the `<g>` element.

Comment: I thought of doing it with a parent div on the svg but this made it simpler and faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: IE11 is the same

Comment: Just came across this issue. This response is the good one, but it's worthy to note that doing a rotation on the group will rotate the element from its (0,0) coordinate. Doing it on the SVG rotates it from its centre. So try something like that rather: `transform="rotate(180 500 250)"`.

Comment: Also to add, when rotating on a contained element a `height` value is required, adding to @Gabriel's point, if your sizes are dynamic you can add `transform-origin="center"` to the element

Comment: In safari the animation also need supply both the from {} and to {}. Only has to {} works in chrome, but the animation will not work in Safari.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson for great answer and highlight out. Though the question does not contain the animation part while your answer mostly solve the issue I met with animation. Just realized that in Safari can not abbreviate the from state as well.

Comment: perhaps you should just [raise a webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/) It seems unlikely anyone with an animation problem will land on this question. Or ask and self answer another question unless there already is a suitable Safari animation question.

Answer (score 5):

Browsers allow you to use CSS on the SVG-elements, so an easy fix is to use the CSS transform instead.

```html
<!-- ( works on all elements ) -->
<path style="transform:rotate(180deg)" />
```

Comment: In my case I applied the style directly to the <svg> element. with no transform-origin, just the transform:rotate(180deg) as such: <svg width="1000" height="500" style="transform:rotate(180deg)" > ....

Comment: This CSS will not work in Safari which is at the center of this question. voted down.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be instead of using the `transform` on the `<svg` element, like this:

`<svg version="1.1" transform="rotate(90)"`

to set it on the `<path` element (for example), like this:

`<path transform="rotate(90 18 18)"`

note that you will need to set the x,y center of rotation (in my example I used `viewBox="0 0 36 36"`)