# Why is D3 Zoom function not working in Safari?

Tags: d3.js, svg, safari

When trying to apply D3 zooming to an svg it works in Chrome browsers but not Safari, is there a fix/ workaround that can be applied for this
[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/jonathan-werrey-easterbrook/pen/ZEzmbNG?editors=1111)

```
(function(){


 d3.select('.container')
   .append('svg')
     .attr('width',500)
     .attr('height',500)
     .attr('x',20)
     .attr('y',20)
     .attr('class','svg')
     .style('background-color','blue');

 d3.select('.svg')
   .append('circle')
     .attr('cx',250)
     .attr('cy',250)
     .style('fill','green')
     .attr('r',50);

 var zoom = d3.zoom()
   .scaleExtent([1, 100])
   .translateExtent([[0,0], [1000, 1000]])
   .extent([[0, 0], [200,200]])
   .on("zoom", zoomed);

 d3.select('.svg').call(zoom);

 function zoomed(){
   var transform = d3.event.transform;
   d3.select('.svg')
     .attr('transform',`translate(${transform.x},${transform.y}) scale(${transform.k})`)
 }

})()
```

Comment: Same problem, but from a different cause in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836886/wheel-event-is-not-fired-on-a-svg-group-element-in-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248512/svg-transform-rotate180-does-not-work-in-safari-11), Safari does not support `transform` attributes on `<svg>` elements. Robert Longson suggests appending a `g` element, and applying the transformation to that, which I've done below.

```js
const svg = d3.select('.container')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('class','.svg')
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',500)
    .style('background-color','blue');

const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'g')

g.append('circle')
    .attr('cx',250)
    .attr('cy',250)
    .style('fill','green')
    .attr('r',50);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 100])
    .translateExtent([[0,0], [1000, 1000]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [200,200]])
    .on("zoom", function zoomed(){
      g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
    });

svg.call(zoom);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Is it just me, or does this appear to not work anymore?