# Wheel event is not fired on a SVG group element in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, safari

I am trying to bind a `wheel` event listener to a SVG group element using D3. It seems the `wheel` event is not triggered when I scroll on the group element in Safari (group is not empty). It works fine on Firefox or Chrome.

```js
let svg = d3.select('svg');

let group = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'my-group');

group.on('wheel', (e) => {
  console.log('wheel!');
  e.preventDefault();
});

group.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .style('fill', 'darkorange');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="900" />
```

However, the `wheel` event is fired in Safari if I bind the listener to the SVG element instead.

```js
let svg = d3.select('svg');

let group = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'my-group');

svg.on('wheel', (e) => {
  console.log('wheel!');
  e.preventDefault();
});

group.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .style('fill', 'darkorange');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="900" />
```

Is there a way to bind `wheel` event to a single SVG group instead of the whole SVG element in Safari?

Comment: It is confirmed as a bug in webkit (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226683#c3). I will post here if I find a good workaround or there are any updates from the webkit team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added

```
d3.select(document.body)
.on('wheel.body', e => {});
```

before binding a `wheel` event to an SVG element.
This solved the problem somehow.

```js
let svg = d3.select('svg');

let group = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'my-group');

d3.select(document.body)
.on('wheel.body', e => {});

group.on('wheel', (e) => {
  console.log('wheel!');
  e.preventDefault();
});

group.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .style('fill', 'darkorange');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="900" />
```

Comment: Oh wow it is very interesting! Have no idea why it would magically solve the problem. Could you please also share this finding on the WebKit issue tracker site (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226683#c3)? It would help the WebKit team to investigate this issue.